# How to combine two sql table in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to compare two tables to check is user data already exits in another table. I show some posts they talk about whereRaw but details is not enough i was try to run query but i am not getting which i want.

UPDATED
I have 2 tables one is for challenges between two people

```
Challenge Table  id,user_one, user_two, data_one, data_two,winner_id
```

And my second table is

```
vote Table id, user_id, battle_id, voted_user
```

I want to check is user already votes the table or not, If yes skip that challenge table and show remain table data to user.

```
$challenges = DB::table('challenges')->whereRaw([
            ['challenges.user_one', '!=', $uid],
            ['challenges.id', '!=', 'vote.id'],
        ])->orWhereRaw([
            ['challenges.user_one', '!=', $uid],
            ['challenges.id', '!=', 'vote.id'],
        ])->get();
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL error you're getting?

Comment: and how does Challenge and Vote tables are connected by which foreign key ?

Comment: challenge id is battle_id, Battle is between user_one and user_two |  in vaotes - user_id is user who voted

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [crossJoin](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

```
$challenges = DB::table('challenges')->crossJoin('vote')
        ->where('challenges.user_one', '!=', $uid)
        ->where('challenges.id', '!=', 'vote.id')
        ->orWhere('challenges.user_one', '!=', $uid)
        ->orWhere('challenges.id', '!=', 'vote.id')->get();
```

Refer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: Joining table make result useless. Is there is any other way to do that without join tables

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1,table2 is actually cross join only